# Nodejs with database for user accounts

Tags: node.js, database, backend, user-accounts

This is not really a question but more a request for a recommendation. So, I learned some front end (html, css and vanilla js) and some back end (nodejs + express) but now I would like to develop my own web app as I think i'll learn a lot while im doing it. My biggest question is on backend, im planning to use nodejs + express and a database (preferencially mysql) connected to it, as I told before i've already learned some back end but i only wrote a server file, I would like to know how this web app should be organized and how to connect the backend to a database. For example, developing a page where users can create and login with their own accounts and have their own data. Could you please give me some good resource where I could build something similar so I would learn it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial and some other in the same website to make a webapp with nodeJS express.js and MySQL so here's the link, have fun !

https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/

Comment: Hello, thank you for the resource but isn't that a little bit old? That article was last edited in 2015 isn't it out of date? Thank you!

Comment: maybe you can check this aswell [link](https://codeforgeek.com/2016/11/mends-mariadb-full-stack-architecture/) but the other tutorial is not too old if you use the latest version of the packages